# AJAX + dynamically adding java script function to the page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am loading a portion of page using AJAX calls, which may contain script functions defined in them . Which are attached with the controls being loaded with different events. Now the problem is that when those events triggered i got the error "object not found" which indicate the function is not found/defined. While using Firebug i can see that the function is defined and available. So how can i make sure that browser can find the respective function.

I tried but either i am missing some thing or either its not working, Here is what i am doing

```
       Page
           --->Partial View A
                  ----->Partial View B
```

Now Page Loads Partial A with Ajax Calls which further loads Partial B with Ajax Calls.Both Partial A & B contains few java script function that logically only associated with them not with master page.
The pages loads fine except the functions could not execute as "Object Not Found" comes in.

Comment: are you using a framework/library or just plain javascript?

Comment: Although i am using JQuery but here this is normal java script inside ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 3):

You should define functions using this syntax:

```
myFunction = function(foo) {}
```

not this syntax

```
function myFunction(foo) {}
```

The second form won't work when eval()'d (which is probably what's happening)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework or library you have to set a parameter in order to evaluate the script present in the response of the ajax request. It's usualy called evalScripts

```
evalScripts:true
```

You can also use the callbacks (success/error) of the request to trigger the events, so that it's easier to keep the code in one place and to avoid situations like this.

If you are using plain javasciprt and the XmlHttpObject, then you have to manually find all the *script* tags in your response and then *eval()* them.